# Confused about Node js two brackets function

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to understand the recursive function in NodeJS, but I'm still confused about the following code and output:

```
var firstf = function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {    
           console.log("counter = " + counter);
           return counter += 1;
           }
    };
var add = firstf();
add();//output 0
add();//output 1
add();//output 2
firstf()();//output 0
firstf()();//output 0
firstf()();//output 0
```

I can understand three add() functions output 0,1,2, but I could not understand why three firstf()() output 0,0,0. what does two ()() mean please?

Also one follow up question: for this line: `var add = firstf();`
the variable add will represents the return function as:

```
function () {    
  console.log("counter = " + counter);
  return counter += 1;
}
```

Ok, the question is that how could this function see the variable counter, since counter in upper level, not defined in this inner function.

Comment: FYI, brackets are `[` and `]`.  Parentheses are `(` and `)`.  Braces or sometimes called curly brackets are `{` and `}`.  So, what you're asking about are parentheses, not brackets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no recursion here.  Recursion is where a function calls itself.  This is called a closure.  Because the inner function contains references to variables in the outer function's scope.  Here's a good [article on closures](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36).  From that article:

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
>   with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment).
>
> In
>   other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope
>   from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time
>   a function is created, at function creation time. To use a closure,
>   define a function inside another function and expose it.
>
> To expose a
>   function, return it or pass it to another function. The inner function
>   will have access to the variables in the outer function scope, even
>   after the outer function has returned.

---

Now, let's diagnose exactly what is happening with `firstf()()`.

First that calls `firstf()`.  That initializes the internal `counter` to `0` and returns a new function.

Then, the second `()` executes that returned function which returns the value of `counter` which is `0` and increments it.

Then, you call `firstf()()` again.  That initializes a new `counter` variable to `0` and returns a new function.  Then, the second `()` calls that function and returns the new `counter` value of `0` and then increments it.

So, that explains why successive calls to `firstf()()` just keep returning `0`.  You keep making a new function and a new counter variable each time.

When you do `var add = firstf();` and then call `add()`, you are storing the returned function and then calling the same function over and over again.  That will keep using the same internal `counter` variable and thus you will see the returned value going up as that internal `counter` variable is incremented each time.

> what does two ()() mean please?

Each `()` attempts to execute a function.  In `firstf()()`, the first `()` executes `firstf()` and gets the function that it returns.  The second `()` then executes that returned function and gets whatever it returns (the counter value).

Comment: Bravo, well explained!

Comment: thank you so much, I added a follow up question, could you please give some insights please! :)

Comment: @Jack - The general etiquette here is that you don't keep adding more questions to your original question as the original question should not be a moving target to answer.  You can sometimes get people to help by asking more things in comments.  In Javascript, a function can see all the variables in its scope.  That includes both the variables defined within it, but also variables defined in higher level scopes above it.  When you have a function declared inside a function that inner function can see all the variables of both functions.

Comment: @ggorlen - Good points.  I added info on closure and recursion to my answer.